# ILMerge - pdb associated with dll is out of date

Tags: c#, google-api, pdb-files, ilmerge

Trying to build executable with all libraries inside with help of ILMerge:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\ILMerge\ILMerge.exe" MyScan.exe DirectShowLib.dll Google.Apis.Auth.dll Google.Apis.Auth.PlatformServices.dll Google.Apis.Core.dll Google.Apis.dll Google.Apis.PlatformServices.dll Google.Apis.Sheets.v4.dll log4net.dll Newtonsoft.Json.dll zxing.dll zxing.presentation.dll /out:MyScan2.exe
```

Got error one of dll's is out of date:

```
An exception occurred during merging:
ILMerge.Merge:  There were errors reported in Google.Apis.Auth's metadata.
        The pdb associated with c:\Projects\Myscan\MYScan\bin\Release\Google.Apis.Auth.dll is out of date.
   at ILMerging.ILMerge.Merge()
   at ILMerging.ILMerge.Main(String[] args)
```

What does it mean? Why `Google.Apis.Auth.dll` pdb is out of date and how to fix that? I have cleaned and rebuilt project, but this not helped.

UPD

I had to delete all pdb's associated with google api. After that I got error:

```
Unresolved assembly reference not allowed: System.Core.
   at System.Compiler.Ir2md.GetAssemblyRefIndex(AssemblyNode assembly)
   at System.Compiler.Ir2md.GetTypeRefIndex(TypeNode type)
   at System.Compiler.Ir2md.WriteTypeDefOrRefEncoded(BinaryWriter target, TypeNode type)
   at System.Compiler.Ir2md.WriteTypeSignature(BinaryWriter target, TypeNode type, Boolean instantiateGenericTypes)
   at System.Compiler.Ir2md.WriteTypeSignature(BinaryWriter target, TypeNode type, Boolean instantiateGenericTypes)
   at System.Compiler.Ir2md.GetBlobIndex(TypeNode type)
   at System.Compiler.Ir2md.GetTypeSpecIndex(TypeNode type)
   at System.Compiler.Ir2md.VisitReferencedType(TypeNode type)
   at System.Compiler.Ir2md.VisitMethod(Method method)
   at System.Compiler.Ir2md.VisitClass(Class Class)
   at System.Compiler.Ir2md.VisitModule(Module module)
   at System.Compiler.Ir2md.SetupMetadataWriter(String debugSymbolsLocation)
   at System.Compiler.Ir2md.WritePE(Module module, String debugSymbolsLocation, BinaryWriter writer)
   at System.Compiler.Writer.WritePE(String location, Boolean writeDebugSymbols, Module module, Boolean delaySign, String keyFileName, String keyName)
   at System.Compiler.Writer.WritePE(CompilerParameters compilerParameters, Module module)
   at ILMerging.ILMerge.Merge()
   at ILMerging.ILMerge.Main(String[] args)
```

Comment: The pdb is (hopefully) not part of your project, but of a dependency. Could be that the shipped pdb in the google nuget is really invalid - I'd simply delete the pdb in the build folder before calling ilmerge and seeing if it helps. Doing that as a workaround seems ok - you really only lose line numbers of exceptions inside the google dll, which seems minor.

Comment: I have deleted pdb's associated with google api, but then got error described in question body UPD

Comment: Going out on a limb: You're creating a .net core application and haven't built a self-contained app.

Comment: I'm creating simple .NET framework single form application

Comment: I have the ILMerge as a post-build step, and had this issue pop up. Based on @Voo's suggestion, I added del $(TargetDir)*.pdb to the post-build before calling ILMerge and that solved it

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure, but I was running into the same error

I found I was getting the error if I renamed the ddl before using ilmerge, even if I renamed the pdb as well.

Leaving the original filename fixed it for me

Answer (score 0):

You are probably facing problems with portable PDBs. See https://github.com/dotnet/ILMerge/issues/11 for more details.
There are four options for you:

1. Delete the problematic PDBs before merging
2. Use the most recent version of ILMerge, that [gracefully declines](https://github.com/dotnet/ILMerge/commit/7cc893279931276cbbb5d6797643549e0858965c) them
3. Use /ndebug switch for the ilmerge command to skip all PDBs
4. select the 'Full' option for 'Debugging information' in [project properties](https://github.com/dotnet/ILMerge/issues/11#issuecomment-532027976)

Options 1-3 lose the debug info for the assembly/ies. Option 4 can only be used if portable .PDBs are not required.